# Is it really that big a deal to switch between different formulas?

Tags: infant, formula

A doctor told us that the all of the "cow milk based" formulas are all the same so it doesn't matter which one we use. So I say we get the cheapest and use whatever free stuff we can get no matter the brand (as long as it's the cow based milk and not, say, soy).

But then people think I'm crazy and the baby is going to have all sorts of problems. And I say just because the baby was fussy one day after switching formula doesn't mean the formula was the reason . . . babies get fussy.

Anyway, am I crazy for switching formulas?

Answer (score 5):

My baby wasn't fussy but my wife was. Result, we went through 5 changes of milk in the first 3 months. My wife, naturally wanted the best for out baby. As we live in China, she was worried about the [safety of domestic milk brands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Chinese_milk_scandal).

We started out with a Dutch brand and she bought two bottles then I pointed out that the milk was form Indonesia and bottled in Hong Kong, so she went off that. We switched to a New Zealand brand. The baby poo became thicker and green. While we were told this was quite normal, my wife demanded another switch. We opted for Bellamy's, an Australian Organic brand at four times the price of the first brand. However, my wife still worried that the shop might be selling fakes so I arranged for an Australian friend to post me out cans of milk powder. This almost doubles the cost of the milk but the Australian price is less than half the price in China so it works out as a small saving. Though still four times higher than if we opted for a local make. My wife is now content with the milk supply.

Long story short, the baby had no problems with any of these changes. I'm sure some brands do tasted different. My wife claims so. Thus some babies might reject some tastes but if your baby likes the milk, an you are happy with the quality, then why not.

Answer (score 3):

[Some](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/5003/112) [answers](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/1706/112) [or comments](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/where-can-i-find-good-research-on-long-term-health-impact-of-different-types-bra#comment3841_2548) on this site indicate that due to strict minimum nutrition standards, formulas are all basically the same.

The only thing I could possibly come up with is taste, but I guess as long as your infant accepts it and doesn't turn purple, I'd say you're not crazy and any formula goes :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, my four kids were a little picky, and we had to try a few brands to find one formula that they each liked. BUt if yours isn't as fussy then go for it. What's your pediatrician say?

Comment: Pediatrician said all formulas are the same . . . I didn't ask if we should stick to just one and I have a feeling they'll repeat the same superstition I hear from everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're crazy. No formula choice is eternally binding.

It so happens that our local store has one brand that is always a good price, so we go with that. But if another brand would be of equal quality and cost 40% less, then I would not have hesitated to switch.

We didn't pick the formula based on any particular name brand - we just saw what the market had to offer and made a decision based on ingredients and price.